# ZF2 MYSQL Event Manager Custom Query

Tags: mysql, events, zend-framework2

I am trying to save an event in MySQL event Manager with two parts as shown below.

I can add it successfully via PHPMyAdmin, but with ZF2 TAblegateway no joy..

Any solution - directly through php would be acceptable for now..

```
$this->tableGateway->getAdapter()->driver->getConnection()>execute($eventSql);
```

$eventSql =

```
"DELIMITER |

    CREATE EVENT slacheckevent9
    ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 2 MINUTE
    DO
    BEGIN

    UPDATE sla AS T1,
    (SELECT eventdata FROM eventdata WHERE eventname = 'CUSTOMER 
    CONTACTED' AND instructionid=3) AS T2
    SET T1.actualtime=T2.eventdata WHERE T1.id = 9;

    UPDATE sla
    SET slasuccess= CASE
    WHEN actualtime <= duetime THEN true
    ELSE slasuccess
    END
    WHERE id = 9
    ;



    END |

    DELIMITER ;";
```

Comment: `with ZF2 TAblegateway no joy..` you're going to have to be a bit more specific than that. Do you get any error messages? log messages? Any indication at all of where the joy went?

Comment: Sorry, it had been a long day and error messages were output in the data of an ajax query, so joy was disappearing along with my will to live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply:

```
$eventSql = "
    CREATE EVENT slacheckevent9
    ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 2 MINUTE
    DO
    BEGIN

    UPDATE sla AS T1,
    (SELECT eventdata FROM eventdata WHERE eventname = 'CUSTOMER 
    CONTACTED' AND instructionid=3) AS T2
    SET T1.actualtime=T2.eventdata WHERE T1.id = 9;

    UPDATE sla
    SET slasuccess= CASE
    WHEN actualtime <= duetime THEN true
    ELSE slasuccess
    END
    WHERE id = 9
    ;



    END
    ";
$this->tableGateway->getAdapter()->query($eventSql, \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
```

Comment: It seems that you don't need the DELIMITER statements.